# How CSS module level number is being chosen by W3C?

Tags: css, specifications, w3c

I'm trying hard to understand the proccess of W3C's workflow. The main thing that I'm trying to understand at the moment is how do they choose what level is particular CSS module.

[For example](https://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work.ru.html) there is only "CSS Intrinsic & Extrinsic Sizing Level 3" and no information about what was happening to this module before, was it ever level 2, or it started from level 3?

And another, bonus question, why some modules in "Working Draft" status are supported wider by browsers than modules in "Candidate recomendation" status.

Comment: browsers do as they want. They might find some WD feature more useful or simply easier to implement than some other CR one, so they make it first. As for the level, that's pretty much on which "version" of CSS they are / will be available.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a programming question at all. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do they choose what level is particular css module?

From the [CSS 2017 Snapshot](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-2017/#css-level-3):

> Modules with no CSS Level 2 equivalent start at Level 1; modules that update features that existed in CSS Level 2 start at Level 3.

---

> Why some modules in "Working Draft" status are supported wider by browsers than modules in "Candidate recomendation" status?

Writing specifications and implementations of them are iterative processes. Problems with existing specs such as missing capabilities or undefined situations are identified, and initial specifications may be written to address them. Then browser makers may prioritise them according to commercial advantage balanced against ease of implementation, or even if an individual developer or group has a particular interest or skill in that area. This in turn leads to knowledge about what works and what doesn't which then gets fed back into producing a better spec. These iterations can continue indefinitely until all the browser makers are satisfied that they've got the spec right and that sufficient implementations meet that spec. Only then can it proceed to recommendation. Each module proceeds at its own pace, and so there are no rules as to where each one is in the process relative to other CSS specs.

Comment: I almost thought the same, but wanted to make sure. Thanks.